# Start a firestore transaction without a transaction.get()

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I want to move a doc from one collection to another. Therefore I want to use a transaction to 1. create the new doc and 2. delete the old one.

I can do the following, which works:

```
db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
return transaction.get(docRef)
  .then(() => transaction.set(newDocRef.doc(docId), doc))
  .then(() => transaction.delete(docRef));
```

How can I rewrite this code to start with a `transaction.set()` instead of a `transaction.get()` since I already have the doc in this context so its redundant. The difference is that `transaction.get()` returns a promise whereas `transaction.set()` returns a `transaction`.

Comment: Have you tried `return transaction.set(newDocRef.doc(docId), doc))
  .then(() => transaction.delete(docRef));` ?

Comment: yeah, that doesnt work out because transaction.set() doesnt return a promise. Maybe one has to wrap the returned transaction into a promise, if thats possible.

Comment: I don't think there's currently any way to do this without having the superfluous `get()` call inside the transaction.

Comment: you can try to wrap this into async await.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you do not want to read the document, you should be using Batched Writes.

[Firestore Docs:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

**Batched writes**

> If you do not need to read any documents in your operation set, you
>   can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains
>   any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations. A batch of
>   writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

Comment: This is not completely right. You may want to use transactions to let it fail in case there's no connection if you have persistence enabled. And it's perfectly possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do that...

The transaction doc:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

> When using transactions, note that:
>
> - **Read operations must come before write operations.**
> - A function
>        calling a transaction (transaction function) might run more than
>        once if a concurrent edit affects a document that the transaction
>        reads.
> - Transaction functions should not directly modify application
>        state.
> - Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

Answer (score 0):

I use transactions when I have persistence enabled and I want some document creation fail when there's no internet connection. This is how I do it:

```
let docRef = db.collection("my-collection").doc();
db.runTransaction(async transaction => transaction.set(docRef, { field: "value"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the "transaction.set" in a Promise:

```
db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
return Promise.resolve(transaction.set(newDocRef.doc(docId), doc))
  .then(() => transaction.delete(docRef));
```